# vba scrape non-static web table data

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a macro that scrape and import tables from a [web page](http://www.neeq.com.cn/static/statisticdata.html), 
More specifically, I want to get two tables[tables pointed by arrows, please ignore the text in the table if it doesn't make sense, I translated using google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQTYo.jpg). These tables are updated automatically so I used IE approach(by @ron), didn't scrape any data. I'm exhausted, can anyone please help me? I'm a vba newbie, appreciate any help.

```
    Sub test()
    ' open IE, navigate to the website of interest and loop until fully loaded
      Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
      my_url = "http://www.neeq.com.cn/static/statisticdata.html"

    With IE
       .Visible = False
       .navigate my_url
       .Top = 50
       .Left = 530
       .Height = 400
       .Width = 400

    Do Until Not IE.busy And IE.ReadyState = 4
       DoEvents
    Loop

   End With

  Set tbl = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("table")
    For Each itm In tbl
         i = 1
        For Each itm2 In itm.Rows
            For Each cell In itm2.Cells
              ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2) = cell.innerText
              i = i + 1
            Next
        Next
   Next
  end sub()
```

Comment: end sub() is incorrect

Comment: sorry, it's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You must select "tr" from your table object For Each Rows
As you use IE, non statix should be return (javascript is executed)

```
i = 1
For Each itm2 In  tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")
```

test with debug.print

you select html then tables -> tr -> td

```
Sub test()
    ' open IE, navigate to the website of interest and loop until fully loaded
      Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
      my_url = "http://www.neeq.com.cn/static/statisticdata.html"

    With IE
       .Visible = False
       .navigate my_url
       .Top = 50
       .Left = 530
       .Height = 400
       .Width = 400

    Do Until Not IE.busy And IE.ReadyState = 4
       DoEvents
    Loop

   End With

  Set tbl = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("table")
    For Each itm In tbl
         i = 1
        For Each itm2 In itm.getElementsByTagName("tr")
            For Each cell In itm2.getElementsByTagName("td")
              ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2) = cell.innerText
              i = i + 1
            Next
        Next
   Next
  end sub
```